# Как убрать обводку выделенного элемента QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox, qstyle

В данном случае можно увидеть рамку в элементе номер 3 (ее нужно убрать)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
import sys


class SelectDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if self.parent().currentIndex() == index.row():
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor(Qt.red)

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setItemDelegate(SelectDelegate(self.comboBox))

        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

я знаю про такое решение

```
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet(''' 
        QComboBox QListView{
            outline: 0px;
        }''')
```

но в данном случае оно не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

когда вышло очередное обновление windows 11 эта обводка пропала. Видимо это системная обводка, которую было не убрать

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо убрать рамку из точек? тогда надо немного иначе

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
outline: 0px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И куда я должен это добавить?

Comment: этот вариант тоже не работает  ```self.comboBox.setStyleSheet('''QComboBox QAbstractItemView{outline: 0px; }''')```

Answer (score 0):

У вас по умолчанию установлен стиль

```
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Windows'))
```

Попробуйте установить другие стили, например:

```
app.setStyle("Fusion")
```

или

```
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('windowsvista'))
```

---

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Попробуйте установить другие стили, например:
#    app.setStyle("Fusion")                                  # <----                 
# или
#    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('windowsvista'))      # <----

    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Windows'))            # <- сейчас у вас 
        
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Эта обводка пропадет, если поставить только стиль fusion, но он сильно меняет QComboBox, так что это не подходит

Comment: @MIkhail вы спросили: "Как убрать обводку выделенного элемента QComboBox?" я вам ответил. Сильно меняет или не сильно меняет это уже вопрос третий.